# auto resizing panel on a form

Tags: c#, forms, panel

I have two panels on a form. I want one of them, when an user maximizes the form, the panel to be maximized too, depending on the form. I tried and the panel is shown on the entire form,hiding the other panel.
Here is my code:

```
public MainForm()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  panel2.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Bottom | AnchorStyles.Right);
  panel2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
  TaskControl t = new TaskControl();
  int x, y;
  x = 0;
  y = 0;
  t.Location = new Point(x, y);
  panel2.Controls.Add(t);
  t.BringToFront();

}
```

---

I managed to do it. I changed the values of Anchor from Properties. Thank you for help!

Comment: Can you re-word the question? It is not very clear what you are trying to achieve...

Comment: If I've understood the question right, the accepted answer is just plain wrong. If you're two panels, one resizes and one doesn't when maximised, the correct thing to do is to use the pre-existing supplied control (splitcontainer, as per my answer) to do it. This is there, it's tested, it just works. If you're wanting some additional functionality, or the split container is otherwise not suitable, please update your post or reply to my answer to explain what it is you're trying to achieve!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should NOT only do so in initialization, but also in Form_Resize event etc. For instance, 
you can handle `Form.ResizeEnd` event, see reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.resizeend.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you want a `splitcontainer`. With this control you get two panels. Set the "fixedpanel" property to the panel that you want to not resize. The other panel will resize as the form is resized (or maximised)